# Best way to call css, js files?

Tags: php, html, css

Suppose that your domain is **domain.com** and you have the following directories and files

```
- index.php
<panel>
- panel.php
<css>
- style.css
<js>
- jQuery.js
```

In **index.php** you may call a css file like "*css/style.css*" or "*domain.com/css/style.css*"
In **panel.php** you may call a js file like "*../js/jQuery.js*" or "*domain.com/js/jQuery.js*"

What is the best method to use? **css/style.css** or **domain.com/css/style.css** ?

Does it make any difference? I am asking because in my case it will help me to use the **domain.com/css/style.css** but is it treated as an external file that may reduce perfomance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can even include all sources with //.
means

```
<script src="//js/jquery.js"></script
```

the Browser takes http or https automaticly.
So the Source can be included for both Ports without any Errors

Comment: Whats the benefit of // instead of /?

Comment: // is an absolute Path like http:// or https:// but the Protocol is choosen by the Browser in coordination with the HTML Document

Answer (score 1):

`css/style.css` will navigate to a folder relative to your current one. If you are in the original index.php, it will work. If you are in `/subfolder/somepage.php`, it will not work because it will try to get your css file from `/subfolder/css/style.css`.

`domain.com/css/style.css` will always work, provided you do not change domain name.

`/css/style.css` is the most generic: regardless of your domain, your page will always navigate from the website root to `/css/style.css`

Comment: None. There can be a speed difference factor if the css file is on a different physical server, but the way you refer to the file in your index.php will make no difference at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use :

```
/css/style.css
```

it is an absolute path, but in the same domain

Comment: css and javascripts are usually cached by browsers

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is no `http://` in front of it, it should be treated as a folder in every browser

Comment: I thought, `domain.com/css/style.css` is just a subdir.

Comment: No, domain.com... is the absolute link

Comment: Sorry for that. Then jerjer answer should be the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it make any difference?

Yes, primarily regarding maintainability. If a file i moved you'll need to recalculate all references for **relative links** (e.g., `../js/jQuery.js`) while **absolute links** (e.g., `http://domain.com/js/jQuery.js` - or simply `/js/jQuery.js`) can be left unchanged.

> I am asking because in my case it will help me to use the **domain.com/css/style.css** but is it treated as an external file that may reduce perfomance?

No, as long as the host is the same the client (browser) should treat it as a "local" link (none of which should directly affect performance, though).

Comment: @mtopia Yes. `domain.com/css/style.css` is a *relative reference* (pointing to `./domain.com/css/style.css` where `.` is the current directory), while `http://domain.com/css/style.css` is an *absolute reference*. From the imaginary page located at `http://domain.com/subdir/page.ext`, `domain.com/css/style.css` will point to `htto://domain.com/subdir/domain.com/css/style.css` while `http://domain.com/css/style.css` will point to just that.

Answer (score 0):

For usual I call it with an absolut path like `/css/style.css`.

Doing so you don't have to worry about changing the domain name in some time (like moving vom dev to production) or from which file (index.php, /panel/panel.php) your calling.

Also be sure to not include a protocol scheme (like `http://`), if you would switch to `https://` the browser would claim some unsafe content, for example.